# Read multiple files and save multiple plots using ggplot in one go

Tags: r

```
library(ggplot2)
rm(list=ls())
bar=read.csv("C:/Users/spider shiyas/Desktop/internship/r/output/bangalore/Area.csv")
attach(bar)
df = data.frame(HSI=HSI,Category)
pic=ggplot(df, aes(x=Category,y=HSI,  fill=Category)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", aes(width=0.3)) +
  geom_text(aes(label=HSI, y=HSI+4*sign(HSI)),size=5)+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(-100,100, 10), labels = 100 + seq(-100, 100, 10))+
  coord_flip() +
  theme_bw()
pic
ggsave(filename="Area.jpg", plot=pic,path="C:/Users/spider shiyas/Desktop/internship/r/output/bangalore")
```

I have done this for 1 variable i.e Area. Similarly I have other variables Age, Income, Source etc.

How can I save all the plots in their respective names?
HSI and Category are columns of each file.

Read multiple files and save multiple plots using ggplot in one go

Comment: You say that a `for` loop didn't work for you. Can you show us what you tried, and tell us what it did instead?

Comment: @Pascal The code is posted

Comment: @RJHunter The code is posted.

Comment: Does all the csv as same king of process

Comment: So as of now you want to read all the .csv of a folder and store it into a variable as data right

Comment: @VigneshKalai exactly. To read all the .csv of a folder and save each plots in .jpg format in its variable's name

Comment: Did this solve your problem

Comment: Error came...Saving 8.4 x 4.93 in image

 Error in grDevices::jpeg(..., width = width, height = height, res = dpi,  : 
  unable to start jpeg() device In addition: Warning messages:

1: In grDevices::jpeg(..., width = width, height = height, res = dpi,  :
  unable to open file 'C:/Users/spider shiyas/Desktop/internship/r/output/bangalore/C:/Users/spider shiyas/Desktop/internship/r/output/bangalore/Age.jpg' for writing

2: In grDevices::jpeg(..., width = width, height = height, res = dpi,  :
  opening device failed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use for loop to traverse through file name and read data and create plot with it

Removed path since both of the input csv and jpg are going to be in the same path

The error showed because the file name consist of full directory

**My modification**

```
library(ggplot2)
rm(list=ls())
filenames=list.files(path ="C:/Users/spider shiyas/Desktop/internship/r/output/bangalore/" ,pattern= '*.csv', full.names = TRUE)
for (filename in filenames){
bar=read.csv(filename)
attach(bar)
df = data.frame(HSI=HSI,Category)
pic=ggplot(df, aes(x=Category,y=HSI,  fill=Category)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", aes(width=0.3)) +
  geom_text(aes(label=HSI, y=HSI+4*sign(HSI)),size=5)+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(-100,100, 10), labels = 100 + seq(-100, 100, 10))+
  coord_flip() +
  theme_bw()
pic
ggsave(filename=gsub(".csv",".jpg",filename), plot=pic)

}
```

Or you could save in another destination using the below code

**My modification 2**

```
library(ggplot2)
rm(list=ls())
filenames=list.files(path ="C:/Users/spider shiyas/Desktop/internship/r/output/bangalore/" ,pattern= '*.csv', full.names = TRUE)
for (filename in filenames){
bar=read.csv(filename)
attach(bar)
df = data.frame(HSI=HSI,Category)
pic=ggplot(df, aes(x=Category,y=HSI,  fill=Category)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", aes(width=0.3)) +
  geom_text(aes(label=HSI, y=HSI+4*sign(HSI)),size=5)+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(-100,100, 10), labels = 100 + seq(-100, 100, 10))+
  coord_flip() +
  theme_bw()
pic
ggsave(filename=gsub(".csv",".jpg",basename(filename)), plot=pic,path="C:/Users/spider shiyas/Desktop/internship/r/output/bangalore/")

}
```

In filename i have only provided the file name removing the path using basename function